# How to get multiple random elements from list in Dart

Tags: dart

When i have list

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

i want to get 3 random elements from list

e.g

```
[1, 3, 4] or [4, 5, 1] or [3, 2, 5]
```

how can i solve that simply

is there any dart library??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous solution is good but could have been written in a more generic way so we don't loose the type information of the `List`. Also, `take` does not return a `List` but instead `Iterable`.

I have rewritten the code to be more generic and shorter by using the cascade operator. I am not sure if you want a `List` or `Iterable` as output so I have made multiple solutions:

```
void main() {
  final items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

  print(pickRandomItems(items, 3));                  // (7, 4, 3)
  print(pickRandomItemsAsList(items, 3));            // [2, 4, 5]
  print(pickRandomItemsAsListWithSubList(items, 3)); // [1, 3, 6]
  print(items); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] (just to show that the original List is untouched)
}

Iterable<T> pickRandomItems<T>(List<T> items, int count) =>
    (items.toList()..shuffle()).take(count);

List<T> pickRandomItemsAsList<T>(List<T> items, int count) =>
    (items.toList()..shuffle()).take(count).toList();

List<T> pickRandomItemsAsListWithSubList<T>(List<T> items, int count) =>
    (items.toList()..shuffle()).sublist(0, count);
```

Instead of using `take` in `pickRandomItemsAsList` you can instead use `sublist`. But the catch with `subList` is that if the `length` are greater than the `List` it will give an error but with `take` you just get all the elements in the `List` shuffled.

Answer (score 2):

Simply shuffle list and take sublist (slice):

```
  List pickRandomItems(List items, int count) {
    final list = List.from(items); // cloning original list
    list.shuffle();                // shuffling items
    return list.take(count);       // taking N items
  }

  List items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  print(pickRandomItems(items, 3));
```